# Jodit -> Hide Toolbar after initialization

Tags: wysiwyg, jodit

i use Jodit as wysiwyg editor and have a beginner question.
At initialization of the editor, i want to hide the toolbar.
This works perfect:

```
var editor = new Jodit('#freitext_oben', {
    fullsize: false, 
      toolbar: false,
      editorCssClass: 'editor_freitext'
});
```

Now i want a custom button which calls a function that toggles the toolbar but i don't know how to set this option.

i need something like

```
function toggle_toolbar() {
        editor.toggleToolbar();
}
```

But i don't know the exact syntax...

Please help ;-(

Answer (score 0):

So here's a way that I've found to do this:

```
public ToggleToolbarVisibility()
{
    if(!editor.editor.toolbar.container.style.display != "none")
    {
        editor.toolbar.container.style.display = "none";
    }
    else
    {
        editor.toolbar.container.style.display = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jodit has `show` and `hide` methods for toolbar, so you can try the following:

```
let isToolbarVisible = false;

function toggle_toolbar() {
    if (isToolbarVisible) editor.toolbar.hide()
    else editor.toolbar.show();

    isToolbarVisible = !isToolbarVisible;
}
```